# how to cut image in 9 pieces and control width and height?

Tags: c#

HI guys i have problem in this code i want to display my photo cut in 9 pieces and display it in 9 pictureboxs to make puzzle game wish anyone could help .
Thanks In Advance

```
var knight = new Image[9];
var H = Image.FromFile("1425435_630471227004342_2061223205_o.jpg");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {

      var index = i * 3 + j;
      knight[index] = new Bitmap(200,200);
      var m = Graphics.FromImage(knight[index]);
      Rectangle r = new Rectangle( i * (knight[index].Width / 3),
                                   j*(knight[index].Height / 3), 
                                   knight[index].Width / 3, 
                                   knight[index].Height / 3);
      m.DrawImage(H, r, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

      m.Dispose();
    }
 }
 pictureBox1.Image = knight[0];
 pictureBox2.Image = knight[1];
 pictureBox3.Image = knight[2];
 pictureBox4.Image = knight[3];
 pictureBox5.Image = knight[4];
 pictureBox6.Image = knight[5];
 pictureBox7.Image = knight[6];
 pictureBox8.Image = knight[7];
 pictureBox9.Image = knight[8];
```

Comment: What *specifically* is wrong with your code?

Comment: doesn't cut the photo as needed there is problem in cut with width and height want them cut in 9 pieces if i make them together get the main photo . @Cyral

Comment: Can you show a visual example of whats wrong happening?

Comment: Do look up the parameters for [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): (H, rDestination, rSource, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); rDestination should be new Rectangle(0,0,w,h)

Comment: i tried that already @TaW but the same photo show not complete and if i make them together i don't get the main photo need to cut any photo with fixed width and height so i divide it by 3 but it doesn't work

Comment: You want to draw to the top left of the fresh bitmap, so x and y must be 0.

Comment: Because your new bitmap will have it's own position (because of the picturebox), you must draw it at 0, 0.

Comment: Looking a bit closer your  code I guess you also want to resize as needed, right? I hope my answer does it, I can't test it atm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle( i * (knight[index].Width / 3),
                               j*(knight[index].Height / 3), 
                               knight[index].Width / 3, 
                               knight[index].Height / 3);
  m.DrawImage(H, r, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

to this:

```
  out of the loop:
  // old size of the parts:
  int ow = H.Width / 3;
  int oh = H.Height / 3;

  // new size of the parts:
  int nw = knight[0].Width;
  int nh = knight[0].Height;

  // inner loop:
  Rectangle rDest   = new Rectangle(0, 0, nw, nh);
  Rectangle rSource = new Rectangle(i * ow, j * oh, ow, oh);

  m.DrawImage(H, rDest, rSource , GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Note: If the proportions of the Original Image and the 9 PBs is different there will be a distortion:

[image]

Comment: now it show 6 pic 3 small and 3 large not show the complete photo

Comment: knight is your array. the code for the Rectangles should go into the inner loop! The widths and heights need only be set once. Note I had an error in their code, look at the corrected code now!

Comment: Whoops, H not I! (The original image!)

Comment: i make it  int ow = knight[j].Width / 3;
 int oh = knight[j].Height / 3; and it showed the left side of photo only as i want but it doesn't show all of the photo

Comment: Well don't change my code to the old mistake! make it as I wrote it (after the last correction!) It is now tested to work, if the pictureboxes are order the right way..

Comment: yes it work and show different parts of the photo but there is problem in width and height photos output are very small and photo are cut in wrong way assume it's (matrix) the col become in row and vice versa i need each part cut in right position row in their place and col in their place

Comment: I though it was right but the /3 part is wrong for the new sizes! - I had mixed up a few of those pictureboxes, creating 3 nice and different errors ;-)

Comment: Sorry for those errors, I usually only post tested code but was rathwer distracted tonight..

Comment: it's ok glad that you help and it work but the problem now the photo as i said after divide the row become col and vice versa

Comment: Well if you have mixed them up, simple exchange them! Either the PBs or the way you set up the loops or the index: var index = i + 3 * j;

Comment: i had found better solution i can change position of the 9 pics as you know any matrix its first col is (0,3,6) so i make it like that  pictureBox1.Image = knight[0];
            pictureBox2.Image = knight[3];
            pictureBox3.Image = knight[6];
            pictureBox4.Image = knight[1];
            pictureBox5.Image = knight[4];
            pictureBox6.Image = knight[7];
            pictureBox7.Image = knight[2];
            pictureBox8.Image = knight[5];
            pictureBox9.Image = knight[8]; and it work as i need thank you so much dear friend

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a separate source rectangle (as TaW mentioned). Also you are not fully occupying the `picturebox`.

Try this code:

```
knight[index] = new Bitmap(640, 360); //enter the size of the original image

Rectangle src = new Rectangle(i * (knight[index].Width / 3), j * (knight[index].Height / 3), knight[index].Width / 3, knight[index].Height / 3);
Rectangle des = new Rectangle(0, 0, knight[index].Width, knight[index].Height);
m.DrawImage(H, des, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```